# unable to parse key's value from json key value response

Tags: shell, awk, jq, yq

Team,

I have below output and json query but am unable to retrieve the value next to mode.

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy -o json | jq .data

{
  "config.conf": "apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1\nbindAddress: 0.0.0.0\nclientConnection:\n  acceptContentTypes: \"\"\n  burst: 10\n  contentType: application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf\n  kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf\n  qps: 5\nclusterCIDR: 10.233.64.0/18\nconfigSyncPeriod: 15m0s\nconntrack:\n  max: null\n  maxPerCore: 32768\n  min: 131072\n  tcpCloseWaitTimeout: 1h0m0s\n  tcpEstablishedTimeout: 24h0m0s\nenableProfiling: false\nhealthzBindAddress: 0.0.0.0:10256\nhostnameOverride: hosta\niptables:\n  masqueradeAll: false\n  masqueradeBit: 14\n  minSyncPeriod: 0s\n  syncPeriod: 30s\nipvs:\n  excludeCIDRs: null\n  minSyncPeriod: 0s\n  scheduler: rr\n  syncPeriod: 30s\nkind: KubeProxyConfiguration\nmetricsBindAddress: 127.0.0.1:10249\nmode: iptables\nnodePortAddresses: []\noomScoreAdj: -999\nportRange: \"\"\nresourceContainer: /kube-proxy\nudpIdleTimeout: 250ms",
  "kubeconfig.conf": "apiVersion: v1\nkind: Config\nclusters:\n- cluster:\n    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt\n    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443\n  name: default\ncontexts:\n- context:\n    cluster: default\n    namespace: default\n    user: default\n  name: default\ncurrent-context: default\nusers:\n- name: default\n  user:\n    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token"
}
```

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy -o json | jq .data.\"config.conf\".mode
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:19): Cannot index string with string "mode"
```

Also, is there a way to just pull it using awk?

Tried:

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy -o json | jq -r '.["config.conf"] | splits("\n") | select( test("^mode") ) | [splits(": *")] | .[1]'
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:19): null (null) cannot be matched, as it is not a string
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a jq-only solution:

```
.data
| .["config.conf"]
| splits("\n")
| select( test("^mode") )
| [splits(": *")]
| .[1]
```

Result using the -r command-line option:

```
iptables
```

### -f option

Rather than fighting with your shell, consider using the -f command-line option of jq, or create an executable script.

Comment: that's a nice one

Comment: may am not using right syntax?
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy -o json | jq .["config.conf"] | splits("\n")
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"\n"'

Comment: @AhmFM with any tool (sed, awk, perl, jq, whatever) you have to enclose command-line scripts in quotes: `jq -r '.["config.conf"]
| splits("\n")
| select( test("^mode") )
| [splits(": *")]
| .[1]' file`

Comment: @AhmFM - The filter I originally gave was for the output you showed.  I've added the `.data` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

By using `jq -r .data.\"config.conf\"` you get raw contents of `config.conf`, which you can then easily grep or whatever, they are not json.

Answer (score 0):

Without a JSON-aware tool, a solution is going to be quite difficult or else very hackish.  If you are looking for something in the latter category, you need go no further than:

```
sed 's/\\n/\
/g' | grep '^ *mode:' | sed 's/ *mode: *//'
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this as robustly as reasonably possible in awk would be (using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match()):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    file = ""
    delete f
}
match($0,/"([^"]+)"[^"]+"(.*)"/,a) {
    file = a[1]
    numTags = split(a[2],tagsVals,/\\n/)
    for (i=1; i<=numTags; i++) {
        tag = val = tagsVals[i]
        gsub(/^\s+|\s*:.*/,"",tag)
        gsub(/^[^:]+:\s*|\s+$/,"",val)
        f[tag] = val
    }
}
(tgtFile == file) && (tgtVal in f) { print f[tgtVal] }

$ awk -v tgtFile='config.conf' -v tgtVal='mode' -f tst.awk file
iptables

$ awk -v tgtFile='config.conf' -v tgtVal='contentType' -f tst.awk file
application/vnd.kubernetes.protobuf
```

You'd just have to figure out how you want to handle duplicate tags like "name" in the data. Looks like there might be a third level of hierarchy in your file you'd need to handle if you want to get at those values.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with it jq and yq combinations

```
kubectl get configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy -o json | jq -r '.data."config.conf" ' | yq '.mode'
```

output:

```
"iptables"
```